# How to download a snippet in GitLab CE (Community Edition, locally hosted)?

Tags: gitlab, code-snippets, gitlab-omnibus

There is no download link. Would prefer command line. The URL for the snippet is

```
http://gitlab.server.edu/group/project_name/snippets/3
```

The URL for what I get when I click "Raw" is the same thing as above but ends in `/raw`.

Sorry, can't give real URLs due to privacy.

I know there is a "copy to clipboard" button, but that won't work on a cluster.

**EDIT**
Looks like `raw.githack.com` will do gitlab, but that won't work for an internal installation.

Comment: Hey drive by downvoter--can you please explain why you would downvote a post asking how to do a perfectly reasonable thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check if [this issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/15580) applies in your case:

> The contents of a private snippet can be read by sending the following request to the GitLab API:

```
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: XXXXXXXXXXXXXX" "http://gitlab-instance/api/v3/projects/1/snippets/6/raw"
```